# Gnucash for Mac has got my locale wrong

Tags: macos, locale, gnucash

My Mac locale is set to Philippines, but Gnucash defaults to Australia since it is the first on the list. How do I fix this?

Comment: What language is set in the Language & Text preference pane?

Comment: English is at the top of the priority list.